# Enlarge SVG group on click, then minimize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have multiple groups of svg elements in one viewport. I want users to click on one group which will hide the other groups and enlarge the selected group to fill the viewport.

So far I have:

```
var continents = $(".continents")

    for (var i = 0; i < continents.length; i++) {
                continents[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                    $(".continents").css("display","none");
                    var currentContinent=this;
                    currentContinent.setAttribute("transform","scale(1.0)")

                })
            }
```

Where the groups are classed ".continents". But this does nothing.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdyeLLm2/2/)

Is it possible to create a zoom effect or simply enlarge a selected group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the code:

1. Not all the groups have the class `.continents`, so not all of the continents will hide when you do this:

   ```
   `$(".continents").css("display","none");`
   ```

   only Asia and Africa do have that class, so only those two will hide.
2. When you set the attribute `transform` here:

   ```
   currentContinent.setAttribute("transform","scale(1.0)")
   ```

   you are not only modifying the value of the `scale()`, but you are also overwriting/deleting the value of the translation.

---

How to fix these issues:

1. Add the class `.continents` to all the groups.
2. Update both the values of `scale` and `translate` for the continent that is clicked, and not only the scale. And this is the tricky part: those values may not be the same for all the continents. For example, for Asia, the target values will be: `translate(-400,439) scale(0.032,-0.032)`, but those values will not work for the other continents. You need to play with different values to find the ones that will work for each particular group.

[You can see it working on this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdyeLLm2/6/) (notice that only Asia will work, the other continents will be displayed outside of the picture until you adjust the translate/scale values).

To make things as generic as possible, you could store the new values in a `data-` attribute (e.g.: `data-transform`), and then update the value of the `transform` by using the value of that `data-` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have class defined on all of your group elements so the click handler and css is only applied to 2 of the groups.

Also, you set all of the displays to none, and never set the display of the selected group back to inline.

The transform is no good since the paths are much larger, have an inverted y axes and are positioned absolutely, so changing the scale from 0.017, -0.017 to 1.0, 1.0 moves them far off the viewport.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdyeLLm2/5/)

```
var prevTransform = null;
var continents = $("g");

for (var i = 0; i < continents.length; i++) {

    continents[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

        var currentContinent = this;

        if (prevTransform == null) {

            console.log("Click!");
            $("g").css("display", "none");
            prevTransform = currentContinent.getAttribute("transform");
            currentContinent.setAttribute("transform", "translate(-20,220) scale(0.025, -0.025)");
            $(currentContinent).css("display", "inline");

        } else {

            currentContinent.setAttribute("transform", prevTransform);
            prevTransform = null;
            $("g").css("display", "inline");

        }
    });
}
```

In this example, South America works best, the others move too far up and right.  Australia moves out of view.